# Socket.Io under multinode cluster on loopback-pm

Tags: nginx, socket.io, cluster-computing, strongloop

I'm using the process manager of strongloop called strong-pm to cluster my node instances, also I use the last socket.io library for my websockets implementation,

I saw that exist a node module call [Socket IO store for clusters](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Socket+IO+store+for+clusters)

To resolve this problem but using Node's native cluster messaging, my question is this module could be used also under strong-pm to resolve the problem of clustering socket.io??, is not how can I resolve he problem of cluster my nodes using strong-pm and socket.io.

Actually a make some tests, only using strong-pm and nginx, I configure nginx to connect the socket.io clients to the server, but when I try to broadcast any event from server to clients the event never is sent, so I supouse that I need any extra module between strong-pm and nginx that manage the sticky-sessions correctly. This suspicious are correct??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem using socket.io redis adapter and force the socket.io client to use websockets protocol like this:

```
var socket = io({transports: ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling']});
```